# undefined method `setup' for main:Object while trying to run controller tests with authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, rspec2

I am a little new to RSpec tests and i am trying to run some controller tests in my Rails 3 application using RSpec 2 and Authlogic 3 authentication.

Following the steps provided by Authlogic documentation (http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/TestCase), i got the following codes in my files:

**spec_helper.rb**

```
require "authlogic/test_case" # include at the top of test_helper.rb
```

**events_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'  
setup :activate_authlogic
```

Running the tests through `rake spec SPEC='spec/controllers/eventos_controller_spec.rb'` i got the following error:

```
events_controller_spec.rb:2: undefined method `setup' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

When i ran the tests before using authlogic i've got no problems.

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and this configuration:

```
ruby - 1.8.7  
rails - 3.0.7  
authlogic - 3.0.2  
rspec-rails - 2.4.1  
factory_girl_rails - 1.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup method is undefined because it's a [Test::Unit method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/TestCase.html#method-i-setup). From the [authlogic docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/TestCase):

> If you are using Test::Unit::TestCase, the standard testing library that comes with ruby, then you can skip this next part. If you are not, you need to include the Authlogic::TestCase into your testing suite.

To do the same thing with RSpec, you have to include Authlogic::TestCase and call activate_authlogic before each spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe EventsController do
  include Authlogic::TestCase

  before(:each) do
    activate_authlogic
  end
end
```